# Mysterious SyntaxError in nosetest of functions/files

Tags: python, syntax-error, nosetests

So I'm trying to write a test for part of a word parser function that will basically confirm whether or not the parser will return what it's supposed to. The part I'm writing a test for is a function called "peek" where it takes a list of tuples (tuples that are in the ('TYPE', 'WORD') format), and returns the value in the 'TYPE' part of the tuple. The code for the peek part of the parser (which is in the file parser.py) is as follows:

```
def peek(word_list):
if word_list:
    word = word_list[0]
    return word[0]
else:
    return None
```

where "word_list" is the list of tuples in question. My test, then, is basically designed to see if the peek function does indeed recognize the tuple list in "word_list" and returns the 'TYPE' value from the tuples it goes through. My code for this test is as follows:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex49 import parser


def test_peek():

    word_list = [('direction', 'north')]
    assert_equal(parser.peek([('direction', 'north')], 'direction')
    result = parser.peek(word_list)
    assert_equal(result, ['direction'])
```

That looks like it should be right, but when I run the nosetests, all I get is this error message:

```
    result = parser.peek(word_list)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I double and triple-checked all my parentheses, commas, operators, and variable values, and I see no SyntaxError, or anything that would lead me to believe something would cause a SyntaxError. Is there something I'm missing here? Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you double and triple-checked, and still couldn't find it, you need to change the way you check.  For example, simply typing `s.count("(")` gives 7 and `s.count(")")` gives 6 for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a missing close paren from the previous line:

```
assert_equal(parser.peek([('direction', 'north')], 'direction')  # <-- ) here
```

Comment: LOL. Wow, my brain must be fried from all the hours I've spent staring at this screen. Thanks, I must have gone past that code like a million times and not seen that somehow. Boy, do I feel like a blind idiot >_<

Comment: We all do it! (Why do you think I knew what it was so quickly? Done it myself a million times. :P)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - The SO dev team should make it so that whenever you tag a question with "syntax-error", one of those blue windows pops up with the message "Did you check the line above?" :)